# How do I add css to datepicker jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I want to personalize the datepicker from jQuery. i want to add `z-index:2`.

```
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
    $("#datepicker").css("z-index",2);
});
```

I know that the line "`$("#datepicker").css("z-index",2);`" doesn't affect datepicker, but I want smth like this. How can I do that ? Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datepicker creates an element with id `#ui-datepicker-div`

so you could just use a general css rule

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
   z-index:2 !important;
}
```

*Side Note*: Personally I wouldn't recommend changing the value in the ui css file itself, as whenever you update jquery ui, you'll have to remember to alter its value every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#datepicker").css("z-index",2); //refers the element
```

The above line does not refer to `datepicker` calendar, it refers to the **element**(maybe `textbox` or `div`).

Rather you should inspect the **`jQuery calendar`** to find the right element.

here is what I got,

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").css("z-index",2); //refers the datepicker calendar div
```

**FYI:** This should be added *after initializing the datepicker*, other wise do it in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

A better method would be to customize the jQuery UI css by overriding the relevant ones in your application css.

e.g.

```
.ui-datepicker { 
    z-index: 2;       
}
```

Just make sure that your application css is loaded last so as to override the jQuery UI classes. You may also use the `!important`, in case you can't.

Also, note that jQuery UI may *not* always give an ID, so it is advisable to rely on original jQuery UI classes.

What I have noticed is, that the calendar is usually wrapped inside a `div` with an `id=fullCalHolder` and `class=hasDatepicker`. So, it would be easier you to find the specific element while you inspect in developer tools.